# Get Data in PowerBI from email Attachments

Tags: email, powerbi, attachment

I receive periodic attachments from a specific email address. This email attachment is a 100kb CSV file. 
I have been able to connect my Exchange account and get the specific emails as the source in Power BI.
But I am unable to extract the CSV attachment from these emails and use them as the source. 
Could you please suggest a solution for my case?